# How to sort the following list with the given class functions?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is the CSortedList.cpp file, where I'm having trouble doing what I want to do.
For example, under the InsertItem function, I'm having trouble sorting the list.

The MoveListItem function is there in order to help sort the list by adding/removing items as needed - it was provided by the professor for this assignment, and I don't think it needs to be changed but I could be wrong.

The RemoveItem function should do exactly what it says - if I were to remove an item from the list, it should be moving the items inside the array 'to the front', with the help of the MoveListItem function.

Finally, per the directions, our professor gave us this function - GetTargetIndex, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with it nor how I'm supposed to use it to help with the coding.

```
#include    <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include    "CSortedList.h"


void    CSortedList::DispRetVal(const char*  szMessage
                                                    , ListRetVal  value) const
{
    #ifdef  DEBUG_LIST
    cerr << szMessage << ": ";
    switch (value)
        {
        case   LIST_FULL:
            cerr << "LIST_FULL\n";
            break;

        case   LIST_EMPTY:
            cerr << "LIST_EMPTY\n";
            break;

        case   LIST_ERROR:
            cerr << "LIST_ERROR\n";
            break;

        case   LIST_SUCCESS:
            cerr << "LIST_SUCCESS\n";
            break;

        case   LIST_INVALID_INDEX:
            cerr << "LIST_INVALID_INDEX\n";
            break;

        default:
            cerr << "Unrecognized error code\n";
            break;
        }
    #endif  // DEBUG_LIST

} 

ListRetVal  CSortedList::GetListItem(int  index, ListItemType  &item) const
{
    // if the list is empty, return an error cocde
    if (true == IsListEmpty())
        {
        DispRetVal("GetListItem", LIST_EMPTY);
        return LIST_EMPTY;
        }

    // if the target location is not within appropriate list boundaries (i.e.,
    // 0 to m_numItems-1), return an error code
    if ((index < 0)  ||  (index > (m_numItems - 1)))
        {
        DispRetVal("GetListItem", LIST_INVALID_INDEX);
        return LIST_INVALID_INDEX;
        }

    // initialize the reference parameter and return
    item = m_items[index];
    return LIST_SUCCESS;

}

ListRetVal  CSortedList::InsertItem(const ListItemType  &newItem)
{
    // if the list is already full, return an error code
    if (true == IsListFull())
        {
        DispRetVal("InsertItem", LIST_FULL);
        return LIST_FULL;
        }

    // Supposed to sort the array
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (newItem < m_items[i])
        {
            MoveListItems(i, MOVE_TO_BACK);
            m_items[0] = newItem;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    m_items[0 + m_numItems] = newItem;
    ++m_numItems;

    return LIST_SUCCESS;

} 

int     CSortedList::MoveListItems(int  targetIndex, int  direction)
{
    int         destIndex;
    int         increment;
    int         sourceIndex;
    int         totalItemsMoved = 0;

    // initialize the source and destination index values
    if (MOVE_TO_BACK == direction)
        {
        sourceIndex = m_numItems - 1;
        destIndex = m_numItems;
        increment = -1;     // move from higher to lower addresses
        }
    else    // MOVE_TO_FRONT
        {
        sourceIndex = targetIndex + 1;
        destIndex = targetIndex;
        increment = 1;      // move from lower to higher addresses
        }

    // loop and "move" elements
    bool        bContinueLoop = true;
    do  {
        m_items[destIndex] = m_items[sourceIndex];
        destIndex += increment;
        sourceIndex += increment;
        ++totalItemsMoved;

        if (MOVE_TO_BACK == direction)
            {
            if ((sourceIndex < targetIndex)  ||  (destIndex < 1))
                {
                bContinueLoop = false;
                }
            }
        else    // MOVE_TO_FRONT
            {
            if (sourceIndex >= m_numItems)
                {
                bContinueLoop = false;
                }
            }

        }  while (true == bContinueLoop);

    return totalItemsMoved;

} 

ListRetVal  CSortedList::RemoveItem(const ListItemType  &targetItem)
{
    // if the list is empty, return an error cocde
    if (true == IsListEmpty())
        {
        DispRetVal("RemoveItem", LIST_EMPTY);
        return LIST_EMPTY;
        }

   // Search for the given value inside the array, and if found
   // delete it.
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (targetItem == m_items[i])
        {
            MoveListItems(i, MOVE_TO_FRONT);
        }
    }

    return LIST_SUCCESS;

}  

// This function is going to be helpful in determining if an item is already in the list,
// or if it isn't, where it belongs.
bool CSortedList::GetTargetIndex(const ListItemType  &newItem, int  &targetIndex) const
{

}
```

In conclusion, my problems are these: I don't understand what 'GetListItem' and 'GetTargetIndex' are supposed to do - they just seem redundant and completely unnecessary, but I can't just not use them because obviously they're there for a reason.

Currently, when I try to sort my list with the given code (inside of 'InsertItem'), the last value is 'lost', so for example if I enter the following:
12
15
3
The following will be displayed:
3
12
3
Instead of what's supposed to be displayed:
3
12
15

And removing a value from the list ('RemoveItem') is just not working at all. If I enter
12
15
3
And I select to remove '3', this displays:
12
3
4217156 (basically a random number)

Now, obviously I don't want the code spoon fed to me - what I'm asking for is where my logic is wrong, and to explain some concepts I may be foggy with?

Thank you.

Comment: First: **Thats a lot of code**. Please reduce it to the problem. Second: You should learn to format code, I think. Thats unreadable.

Comment: "*This is main - this works perfectly fine and nothing in the code needs to be changed here. I'm just showing this so you have an idea as to what I'm doing.*" If it has nothing to do with the problem, **JUST REMOVE IT**. One suggestion: Never say *"this code works perfectly"* on a SO question. Even if it works, anyone can see many problems on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I have deleted everything that is unnecessary.

Comment: *"I don't understand what `GetListItem` and `GetTargetIndex` are supposed to do."* - From the looks of it, `GetListItem` encapsulates access to an internal array. It does bounds checking and checks if the array is empty and responds to these situations with error messages. As for `GetTargetIndex`, I can't tell you what it does as I haven't seen its implementation nor its use.

Comment: Fwiw, the comment in your `GetListItem` "initialize the reference parameter and return" If you think that code does *exactly* what that comment says, I'll have to disappoint you. If the intent was to copy the item to the referenced target, that it *does* do.

Comment: To tackle the first problem: if I add the numbers 12, 24, 55, 1 to the array, it's supposed to display back to the user the following: 1, 12, 24, 55. However, what I'm currently seeing is this: 1, 12, 24, 1. Why is the last number being replaced by the first number?